# UICollectionViewLayout for potentially millions of items

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

So I have a UICollectionView using a custom layout. I use prepareLayout to set up the attributes, but now my dataset has grown and pulls the info from a database & there are potentially millions of items - obviously I can't store the attributes for so many (it does in fact crash due to memory problems).

I've trawled SO & the Apple Docs for examples like mine which use custom layouts, but they all preload the layout info. If anyone can help me with how I should implement the below methods, I'd be grateful -

```
-(void)prepareLayout // does this actually need to do anything in my case?
-(NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect // how do I calculate this on the fly?
```

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably obvious to most of you, but it took me a little while to figure it out.

prepareLayout does nothing if you don't override it - in my case here, as I don't want to preload all the layout info for 1000s of cells, I don't override it.

My implementation of layoutAttributesForElementsInRect: is here -

```
-(NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSMutableArray *allAttributes = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSInteger startItem = MAX(0, (NSInteger)(rect.origin.y / self.cellHeight) * kDaysInWeek);    
    NSInteger endItem = MIN(kNumDaysInCalendar, startItem + (NSInteger)((rect.size.height / self.cellHeight + 1)) * kDaysInWeek);

    for (int i = startItem; i < endItem; i++)
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0];
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *layoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:indexPath];
        layoutAttributes.frame = [self frameForCellAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        [allAttributes addObject:layoutAttributes];
    }

    return allAttributes;
}
```

I realized that this method is called for each new screen full, the rect passed is the window onto the visible content, so all I needed to do was to return an array of the attributes for each item which would be in that rect - I have another method, frameForCellAtIndexPath: , which calculates the frame for a cell at a given indexPath.

Now it works perfectly with no memory-hogging preload.